# Django many-to-many field copy

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a Django model with 2 many-to-many fields. When the model is saved from the admin interface I need to check if the second field is blank and if it is blank then I need the items from the first fielded copied to the second. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

Matthew's answer seems like it would work great but I can't get the instance to save after I copied the field. I have tried instance.save() without any success.

Comment: I usually debug with python's pdb to check what is happening, try to put an import pdb; pdb.set_trace() just before the instance.save() line and press "s" to enter the function and see what is happening, with "n" you go next. here is a [tutorial](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/python-debugger/) just in case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signal to be use is not `post_save`, rather `m2m_changed`, that is sent much after the model is saved to the database.

```
@models.signals.m2m_changed(sender=MyModel.second_m2m.through)
def duplicate_other_on_this_if_empty(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    # just before adding a possibly empty set in "second_m2m", check and populate.
    if action == 'pre_add' and not pk_set:
        instance.__was_empty = True
        pk_set.update(instance.first_m2m.values_list('pk', flat=True))

@models.signals.m2m_changed(sender=MyModel.first_m2m.through)
def duplicate_this_on_other_if_empty(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    # Just in case the "first_m2m" signals are sent after the other
    # so the actual "population" of the "second_m2m" is wrong:
    if action == 'post_add' and not pk_set and getattr(instance, '__was_empty'):
        instance.second_m2m = list(pk_set)
        delattr(instance, '__was_empty')
```

*Edit: next code is simpler, and based upon new knowledge on the models definition*

In your code the 'first_m2m' signals are sent before the the 'second_m2m' (it really depends on your model definition). So we can work on the assumption that when the 'second_m2m' signals are received, the 'first_m2m' is already populated with current data.

This makes us happier, because now you only need to check the m2m-pre-add:

```
@models.signals.m2m_changed(sender=MyModel.second_m2m.through)
def duplicate_other_on_this_if_empty(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    # just before adding a possibly empty set in "second_m2m", check and populate.
    if action == 'pre_add' and not pk_set:
        pk_set.update(instance.first_m2m.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Comment: according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed there is no 'before_add' and 'after_add'. Do you mean 'pre_add' and 'post_add'?

Comment: yes, of course. Sorry I will correct it. (A more complex version of) This is a method I am currently using to ensure that the content of a m2m is always a subset of another (say "enabled" and "active" things, where active must be enabled otherwise they are ignored)

Comment: It's not working for me and I can't figure out why. I'm printing a couple logs and I'm noticing that missing_field_2 is executing before missing_field_1. It then proceeds to throw an error saying __was_empty is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: There are a couple of errors in the logic of the code I have written. I will correct them now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a post-save signal. This looks like it might be the best way to handle your needs here: the bonus is that it will work outside of the admin, too.

```
@models.signals.post_save(sender=MyModel)
def duplicate_missing_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.my_second_m2m.count():
        instance.my_second_m2m.add(*instance.my_first_m2m.all())
        # or *instance.my_first_m2m.values_list('pk', flat=True), I think
```

My code may not be quite right: You'll want to read up on signals in django.

Comment: Seems like a great solution, but I can't get the instance to save after adding the values. I have tried instance.save() but that nots working. Any ideas?

Comment: The post_save signal is sent after saving, but the m2m insert queue is already done, so you can't modify it there. Use the m2m_changed instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the clean method to do extra validation, so if the second many2many is blank you can set the default values, for example:

```
def clean(self):
    super(MyClassModel, self).clean()

    if not self.MySecondMany2Many:
        # fill data
```

you should set this code in you models.py inside your class. if clean doesn't work because the model needs to be saved you could override the save function too, it's the same procedure.

I havent test it and I don't think you can check if a many2many field is blank that way, but you should get the idea :)

Comment: Hmm. Doing stuff with m2m fields before saving can die in a big way: it attempts to use the PK before there is one.

Comment: then you could override the save better. But now that Matthew posted about post_save signals, I agree that is a cleaner solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [admin save override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)  definition from here, just override it and check if related field is empty, if so, save the object, and get the related data from the second M2M and set it to first M2M and save it again...